# How to get key contains object in underscore?

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

I need to find a `key` that contains an object in `a`. It should not return me a key that contains array or string . For example in `a` it should return me `d` but not `b` or `c`

```
a = {"b" : "hi","c":[1,2,3],"d":{"2:":3}};
```

Here is the snipped I tried. It returns me first instance of Object. But I dont need Array instance just a dict.

```
var _ = require(underscore);    
_.findKey(a,_.isObject);
```

Comment: `_.isObject` won't work for this, because arrays are objects.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular JS for this:

```
var keysThatContainObjects = Object.keys(a).filter(function(k) {
    return typeof a[k] === "object" && !Array.isArray(a[k]);
}); //["d"]
```

1 line

```
var keysThatContainObjects = Object.keys(a).filter(function(k) { return typeof a[k] === "object" && !Array.isArray(a[k]); }); //["d"]
```

Comment: what if the object has a `length` property? Maybe it would be better to use `!Array.isArray(a[k])`...

Comment: @RobM. -- Good point, made the edit - definitely didnt think of that.

Comment: any way to do in one line,,,thats wat my interest !!!!! and thats the reason to try it in underscore

Comment: @VivekSrinivasan -- Remove the line breaks - now it's one line.

Comment: Or use ES6 fat arrow function `k => typeof a[k] === "object" && !Array.isArray(a[k])`

Comment: i hope using `.find` instead `.filter` will directly fetch me the key instead of array. Anyways I need first instance of key not all. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @VivekSrinivasan yes, `find` will find you the first thing. Both `find` and `filter` take the same arguments but they just produce different things.

Answer (score 0):

I very clean way would be to use `pick` from [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#pick)

```
var a = {"b" : "hi","c":[1,2,3],"d":{"2:":3}};
var aFiltered = _.pick(a, function() {
  return _.isObject(value);
});
```

Comment: it picks even an array type ...I need only dict . in the return statement we need negate array type.